# A Shape that returns multiple options

Tags: swiftui

So what I'm thinking is if there is a way to create a `Shape` that when initialized can return one of any option that the caller would like. For example:

```
struct LetterTemplates: Shape {

   init(letterTemplate: LetterTemplate) {
    // This is where I'm confused. Can I somehow select which path to return based on some input           by the caller??

   }

   func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { ... } // Short Letter Template
   func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { ... } // Long Letter Template
}
```

Comment: Why can't you store `letterTemplate` in local property and use later in `path(in...` func?

Comment: Can I add a parameter to a system called method? Something like

`func path(in rect: CGRect, template: LetterTemplate) -> Path` 

And then `switch` on the template? Is that what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

What you're directly asking about is the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). To accomplish it in a language with closures, when they need to be forwarded to methods, you do this (with real implementations instead of `_ in fatalError()`):

```swift
struct LetterTemplates: Shape {
  init(letterTemplate: LetterTemplate) {
    switch letterTemplate {
    case .:
      path = { _ in fatalError() }
    case .:
      path = { _ in fatalError() }
    }
  }

  private let path: (CGRect) -> Path

  func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { path(rect) }
}
```

However, this is not the SwiftUI way. The SwiftUI way is to have a collection of types that all implement a particular protocol, and then, to use autocomplete with that protocol's name to pick out particular implementations.

[People are trying to improve the usability of that](https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0299-extending-static-member-lookup-in-generic-contexts/43958).

Answer (score 1):

You could try approaching the problem like this: define an enum with possible templates:

```
enum LetterTemplate {
    case short
    case long
}
```

Than use that enum to initialise an instance of LetterTemplateShape and use it to choose the right path to draw in `path(in:)`:

struct LetterTemplateShape: Shape {

```
let letterTemplate: LetterTemplate

init(letterTemplate: LetterTemplate) {
    self.letterTemplate = letterTemplate
    
}

func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    switch letterTemplate {
    case .short:
        return ShortLetterTemplateShape().path(in: rect)
    case .long:
        return LongLetterTemplateShape().path(in: rect)
    }
}
```

}

And then declare the actual paths for each case of the enum as separate shapes:

```
struct ShortLetterTemplateShape: Shape {

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // actual implementation
    }
}

struct LongLetterTemplateShape: Shape {

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // actual implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also the strategy pattern, but one of the ways it was done in OOP languages. The switch can be moved earlier and performed once. The last snippet of your code is how Apple's code accomplishes the task. They just don't bother with the other parts.

Comment: The switch is performed once in both cases, with the difference that my implementation stays with value types only without adding a reference type to the equation.